# High school students publishing math papers

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals, paper-submission

I am a high school student who has recently established a few theorems regarding geodesic convexity in metric spaces. Most of the proofs are accessible to undergraduate students. I don’t want to publish in “top” journals, nor do I think my paper would be accepted for that matter. What are some quality journals aimed at undergraduate math I should consider publishing in?

Comment: Is your work "new"? Have you done a literature search?

Comment: Thoroughly, I have included some known results but referenced all of them. Actually, in the abstract, I warn that the purpose of the paper is to clearly present known results, but to also include new results.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617787/how-can-a-high-schooler-get-more-involved-in-mathematics for general advice on math research for high school students.  There's a useful list of possible journals at https://libguides.citytech.cuny.edu/c.php?g=988990&p=7153843.

Comment: Is there a university with a Math department anywhere near you ? If so, find out which of the faculty there might be best to advise of publishing on this topic. They might know publications relevant to your theorems. Bon courage et bonne chance !

Comment: Good advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in general, a paper that "clearly present[s] known results" is not something that would be published. But if you have developed something truly novel, then you can certainly try to find a journal.

I don't have any specific recommendations (that would require a detailed understanding of your paper) but I can give you some tips on finding decent journals that might consider your work.

Right off the bat, I would suggest talking to someone with some experience in publishing. If you are working with a teacher (or university professor) ask them. If you are not, it might be good to find someone willing to give you some guidance. This will help with the logistics of publication as well as help you polish up your paper.

The next step would be to search on Google Scholar for similar papers to get a sense of where others are publishing. There are also some tools like [Scimago](https://www.scimagojr.com/) that list/rank journals. I would take everything on that site with a grain of salt, but it is a good start. You could also try a simple search for "student journals" or something similar. Again, this is basic but a good start.

Once you have found a handful of journals take a look at their "Aims and Scopes" page. This will contain a description of the types of papers they are looking for. This can help you further narrow down your search.

By the end of this process, you should have a few target journals and you can pick one to submit to.

Some general tips:

1. Journals may be ranked using "Impact Factors". Higher is better here but don't worry too much about this.
2. Avoid "predatory" journals. Anybody promising to publish your paper quickly for a nominal fee is not running a legitimate journal. There is a lot of subtlety to this but, in general, any journal that has as old/outdated website, promises fast review, feels off, etc... should be avoided.
3. Your best bet is student focused journals. You can find these by looking up university websites and/or searching "student journals".
4. Don't take it personally if you submit to a journal and are rejected. It happens to everyone. Just try to improve the paper and then move on the next journal on your list.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The Mathematical Association of America (MAA) has a journal aimed at college teachers that might be appropriate, depending on the nature of your paper. https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal.

I thought they also had a journal for students, but can't find it now. You might search around. You might look at: https://www.maa.org/member-communities/students/meetings-and-conferences-for-students.

Answer (score 3):

First put it up as a preprint on arxiv.org.
You must learn LaTeX in order to publish math. If you're talented enough to cook up new math, you can learn LaTeX (too many 'amateur' mathematician do not bother with LaTeX. Not using LaTeX is a huge red flag, and won't be taken serious by anyone in the math community).

Comment: Although I fully agree with the sentiment, I think that we can promote LaTeX better by focusing on its advantages (i.e best software for typesetting maths, excellent typography, completely free, etc) rather than scare-mongering young colleagues that they won't be taken seriously. LaTeX is not a gatekeeping tool, it's a wonderful software for creating beautiful maths.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I totally agree with this. However, I also think typing up math is underestimated. It requires more skills than one usually learns in high-school (or university, for that matter).

Comment: Of course, I wrote the paper in LaTeX.

Comment: I plan on submitting the paper to the https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/rhumj/ which prohibits preprints.

Comment: @user227351 well, it does not allow publication elsewhere, but DO allow you to put stuff on peronal web page. Arxiv is somewhere between - it is not really considered to be 'more' published if it is on arxiv, compared to your personal web page. But yeah, looks like a perfect journal to submit your work.

Comment: Glad to hear that!